# wrong filename in cron configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab

Configuring cron with the following lines (using sudo crontab -u daemon -e)

```
* * * * * bash /path/to/magento/cron.sh --mode default >> /path/to/magento/var/log/cron.log 2>&1
* * * * * bash /path/to/magento/cron.sh --mode always >> /path/to/magento/var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

or running the following line from shell

```
bash /path/to/magento/cron.sh --mode always
```

gives this error:

```
Could not open input file: /path/to/magento/--mode
```

Why does the filename get truncated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the script `cron.sh` you will see that it expects two parameters if you want to use a mode: The first parameter is the cron script and the second is the cron mode.

In your case the first parameter is "--mode" and this is used as script in Magento's installation directory - that's why `/path/to/magento/--mode` is called as script file.

Use the following syntax:

```
bash /path/to/magento/cron.sh cron.php -mdefault
bash /path/to/magento/cron.sh cron.php -malways
```